# Why is the component not being updated after changing object properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

There are other Stack Overflow threads that are kind of related to this question, but very briefly answered. They say, "Use the spread operator". But why?

In the below code, I'm updating upon clicking the `firstName` property of the `user` object, which is a `state`, but nothing is happening. Why is that?

```
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    firstName: "Jhon",
    lastName: "Doe",
  });
  const changeFirstName = () => {
    const newUser = user;
    newUser.firstName = "David";
    setUser(newUser);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>First Name: {user.firstName}</p>
        <p>Last Name: {user.lastName}</p>
      </div>
      <button onClick={changeFirstName}>Change First Name</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React won't update the DOM every time you give the same `state` to a `setState`. For primitive values like `Number`, `String`, and `Boolean`, it's obvious to know whether we are giving a different value or not.

For referenced values like `Object` and `Array`, on the other hand, changing their `content` doesn't flag them as different. It should be a different memory `reference`. See your commented code to understand what you are doing wrong:

```js
const newUser = user;        // does a reference copy, means newUser === user
newUser.firstName = "David"; // changes its content, but still newUser === user
setUser(newUser);            // at this point, it's like nothing has changed
```

A solution could be the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which will create a copy of your existing object but on a new memory `reference`, and then you overwrite the properties that you want to change:

```js
const newUser = {...user, firstName: "David"}; // creates a copy of user on a new reference and updates its firstName field
setUser(newUser);                              // new reference is given to setUser
```

Comment: See for full reference on how to update arrays & object in React state: https://dev.to/andyrewlee/cheat-sheet-for-updating-objects-and-arrays-in-react-state-48np

Answer (score 0):

Let me add a reference to the React [`useState`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-the-screen-doesnt-update) documentation:

> #### I’ve updated the state, but the screen doesn’t update
>
> React will **ignore your update if the next state is equal to the
> previous state,** as determined by an [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) comparison.
> This usually happens when you change an object or an array in state
> directly:
>
> ```
> obj.x = 10;  //  Wrong: mutating existing object
> setObj(obj); //  Doesn't do anything
> ```
>
> You mutated an existing `obj` object and passed it back to `setObj`,
> so React ignored the update. To fix this, you need to ensure that
> you’re always [*replacing* objects and arrays in state instead of
> mutating them](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-objects-and-arrays-in-state):
>
> ```
> // ✅ Correct: creating a new object
> setObj({
>   ...obj,
>   x: 10
> });
> ```